# Remove blood stains from wood tray

Tags: wood

I am trying to remove blood stains from a wood tray
I had in my refrigerator.

It came from meat I had defrosting above the tray.

I tried bleach, baking soda and vinegar.

Any other methods I can use?

Comment: (If that's from meat, then AIUI it's more likely to be [tissue fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracellular_fluid) than blood. I don't know if that affects the solution, though.)

Answer (score 2):

"THE" cleaning solution for blood is hydrogen peroxide (H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>, "oxygenated water"). You can find 3% diluted hydrogen peroxide in pretty much any pharmacy.

This 3% solution can be used safely even on the human body, and is very useful even on (small) open wounds. It cleans and help healing at the same time.

Notes:

- Hydrogen peroxide works best on fresh blood. It has lower efficiency on old blood, or on blood already "treated" with other substances.
- Because of the low concentration, you might need to use quite a big quantity of the solution, but considering the low price, it should not be a problem.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Chasing Stars  Thanks, I will try it.